# How to create form that allows only one character in a cell

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to create a Microsoft Word document (doc or dot), that faciliates filling a form (or a table) in such a way that user types one character and the cursor is moved to the next cell. Like in the following exhibit for a eight-letter word:

[image]

Currently, I am achieving this by using one-row table and pressing Tab after each character.

Is there a way to do this either by customizing table oraz using the Form Controls from the developer tab?

Comment: why no using fixed width character font instead  (even with a custom background)? Because that seems like a lot of hassle

Comment: @dvvh It is a good idead. Is fixed width settable on any font or do I have to find a font that has fixed width by design? Write it as an answer so I can upvote that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told already, I might be easier to use a fixed width font, you have to use a font that has a fixed width by design, to name a few on windows system:

- Consolas
- Courrier New (most common)
- Lucida console